# How to disallow child element being expanded out of parent element in grid layout

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have grid layout with two inner elements, I want second element(bbbb row) should be limited by (aaaaa row)

```
<style>

#container {
    display: grid;
    width: 90%;
    justify-content: center;
    background: green;
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-flow: row;
}
#inner {
    display: grid;
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
}
#inner2 {
    display: grid;
    width: 100%;
    background: yellow;
}
</style>


<div id="container">
    <div id="inner">aaaaaaaaa</div>
    <div id="inner2">bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</div>
</div>
```

so, this is how it looks like now [bad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQB7W.png)
and how it should be(part of bbb is hidden) [good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0U1X.png)

Comment: Can the markup be changed ?

Comment: @Paulie_D Don't see how this is a duplicate that question is about Flexbox and this specifically asks for a CSS Grid solution

Comment: The same issue applies to CSS-Grid as well as flexbox hence the title of the duplicate question. Whilst that actual *question/ specifically refer to flexbox, it applies to CSS-Grid also.

Comment: @Paulie_D we needed the duplicate for the row direction, not the column one